Glue Crawler creates a single table instead of multiple tables
I have the following structure in S3
...
├── data
│   ├── hist
│   │   ├── mongodb
│   │   │    ├── mongodb_attempts
│   │   │    │   ├── attempts_20240513
│   │   |    │   │   ├── 000_part_0.parquet
│   |   |    │   │   ├── 000_part_1.parquet
│   |   |    |   │   ├── ...
│   │   │    │   ├── attempts_20240520
│   │   |    │   │   ├── 000_part_0.parquet
│   |   |    |   │   ├── 000_part_1.parquet
│   |   |    |   │   ├── ...
│   |   |    |   ...
             ...

I've created a crawler with data source .../hist/mongodb/mongodb_attempts/ but instead of creating a table for each attempts_YYYYMMDD, it creates a single table "mongodb_attempts". It makes sense since the schema is the same and Glue treats them as partitions of a single table.
However, how can I achieve this behavior of creating one table per inner prefix? Writing all paths as data sources is not an option because new ones are added weekly. Is there a feature that must be enabled? Otherwise, I'm thinking of using a lambda function to modify the data sources.
Thank you
My solution: since I couldn't find any configuration on Glue Data Catalog, I ended up creating a lambda function triggered by an eventbridge rule weekly. The lambda lists the S3 folder, updates the crawlers and run them. I used SDK Glue client.

This can be done via S3 schema grouping. Choose the option Create single schema for each S3 path. And define the depth level. In your case I believe table level would be 5.

More details can be found here

But this is the opposite of what I want. I don't want to combine schemas that are similar into one unique table. I want to separate them. Giving the level doesn't work either: data source path is bucket_name/data/hist/mongodb/mongodb_attempts/, with level 5, it crawls one single table as it already did

I believe you misunderstood my question: I don't want one table mongodb_attempts, I want one table for each subfolder in mongodb_attempts. That's why I said I should specify dinamically all paths corresponding to each subfolder
